# How to access bash variable in python script via hql file(bash-hql-python)

Tags: python, bash, shell, hive

**Goal :** Access bash variable in python script.

***Bash File* :**

I have bash file where I have declared my variable.
i.e. `export var="/abc/xyz/file.txt"`

This bash file will make call to hql(hive) file.

***Hive File*:**
This hql file will call python script to perform some operation.

*What I want to do is to access bash variable(var) in python script.*

I tried using below logic in python script but I was not able to access that variable.

```
import os

res = os.environ['var']
```

Please suggest some alternate solution to achieve this.

Comment: Would you consider saving var just to a text file temporarily with bash, then access that file from python?

Comment: how about this, pass bash variable to hive and then read those hive variable in python.

Comment: The reason behind accessing bash variable in python script is to avoid hardcoding the file path in python script. @Pal Szabo

Comment: How to achieve that? @Gaurang Shah